# Snort not sending alert log file to syslog server?

Tags: ubuntu, logging, rsyslog, snort

I am set up with three virtual machines running Ubuntu - a Server, Client, and Gateway. I am tasked with setting up Snort on the Gateway to monitor "attacks" from the Client to the Server. Snort is supposed to send the log files to a rsyslog server that I have set up on the Server. I am having trouble getting these logs to send.

In the snort.conf file, I set up:

```
output alert_syslog: LOG_AUTH LOG_ALERT
```

I flushed my iptables and opened everything for testing purposes (nmap reveals 514 is indeed open). I edited the rsyslog.conf file on the Gateway and added:

```
*.* @192.168.50.5
```

On the rsyslog.conf file on the Server, I added:

```
*.* /var/log/snort.log
```

And uncommented the following in both:

```
$ModLoad imudp.so
$UDPServerRun 514
```

When I run (eth2 = Client):

```
snort -A console -i eth2 -c /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

And ping the Server from the Client (I have a Snort rule to capture ICMP), a log file gets created on the Gateway in /var/log/snort/snort.log.xxxxxxxxxx. Nothing shows up on the Server though. Watching packets on Wireshark, I get two Syslog messages when I start Snort and two more when I exit (^C). The AUTHPRIV.INFO just says "session open for user root" and "session closed for user root":

[image]

For the record, I was attempting to follow this tutorial here:

> http://books.google.com/books?id=TPXusCxyKXAC&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=log+local0+snort.conf&source=bl&ots=PeMZAPE7DF&sig=Q4R5rkbvDZjfwoCOGL7Gy-1gHho&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gYw_VL3iBcHjoAS0j4KQBw&ved=0CFUQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q&f=false

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Try restarting the syslog service.

Comment: I did... multiple times. And I tried restarting the VM's. And re-installing rsyslog.

Comment: what versions are you using? of ubuntu, snort, syslog?

Comment: Snort - 2.9.6.2, Ubuntu - 14.04, Rsyslog - 8.4.2

Comment: If you specify *.* /var/log/everything.log, will it record messages to the local syslog instance?

Comment: No it will not... just to the /var/log/snort/snort.log.xxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that if the syslog messages about sessions opening and closing are getting through, then rsyslog is presumably doing its thing at both ends (but confirm it by sending to syslog on the gateway using `logger`).  Also, the fact that the log file gets created on the gateway suggests that the log messages are being mishandled on the gateway, rather than later in the chain process.

I'd be looking to confirm that snort is in fact sending UDP to syslog.  Do you have the expected packets on port 514, presumably on the loopback interface of the gateway?

It looks like you could just circumvent the local syslog, and go directly to the server host:

output alert_syslog: host=192.168.50.5:514, LOG_AUTH LOG_ALERT

If that doesn't appeal, what happens if you explicitly send the snort output to localhost:514?  Or to a different IP on that host.

Are there firewall issues that might block the packets to port 514 on the gateway?

You did restart snort to pick up the new configuration?  It is reading the configuration file you think it is?  (Try specifying that explicitly with `-c`, and/or confirming that's part of the command-line you see with `ps`).

(At some point, you'll want to limit what gets filed as snort messages, but that's not what you're currently stuck on).

Comment: Finally got it figured out. Turns out that the '-A console' part of the command that I was using to run snort was causing some problems with not logging. Besides that, declaring host=ip:514 worked. And I also limited the Snort messages (kept getting massive 4-5 gb log files).

Answer (score 1):

Note that on Ubuntu Snort logs with LOG_AUTH facility by default so you need to `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` rather than `/var/log/syslog`. Just a note from someone who got stuck on this for a while :)

Comment: I got stuck into this for almost 5 hours and your comment saved me from psychological breakdown.
Thanks!